# Reading mat file error with R.matlab & rmatio

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to read a .mat file using either R.matab or rmatio and I am receiving an error that I do not understand.

With R.matlab, I receive the following error:

> Error in mat5ReadArrayFlags(this) :    Unknown array type (class). Not
>   in [1,15]: 17

My R code is:

```
 path<-('C:/Bita/data')
    pathname <- file.path(path, "EuropeStockLevelWorkspaceStyleCountryAlpha.mat")
    dfEuropeStyleCountry <- readMat(pathname)
```

With rmatio, I receive the following error:

> Error in read.mat(pathname) :    InflateDimensions: Reading dimensions
>   expected type MAT_T_INT32

My R code:

```
 path<-('C:/Bita/data')
    pathname <- file.path(path, "EuropeStockLevelWorkspaceStyleCountryAlpha.mat")
    dfEuropeStyleCountry<-read.mat(pathname)
```

My .mat file is too huge and I have no way to post its structure as I do not have access to its structure.

Comment: Have you verified the `.mat` file opens correctly in Matlab?  If so, start small:  create a small subset of your data (in Matlab) and dump to a different `foo.mat` file; see if that opens properly.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Matlab, this is a file passed to me

Comment: Then call the sender and have him reverify it as well as the Matlab version which created it. Possibly `R.matlab` doesn't support one version or another.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you think this is a new bug?.

In my case the examples in the package work. But one file in particular does not. Maybe it's too large for this tool?. My file is 76MBytes

Comment: Not knowing your MATLAB version and without access to the file it is difficult to be sure, but I faced this error when trying to read a MAT file with a dataset (version R2012b).